# how to scale edge related number by a vertex related number in igraph?

Tags: r, igraph, network-analysis

I have a graph data frame as created by the function `graph.data.frame` from the `igraph` package. My edges contain information about the "strength of the relation" and my nodes contain information about the "strength of the node".

What I would like to do is to scale the strength of the relationship by the strength of the individual nodes they relate to.

For my reproducible example, i am going to use the setup from the `igraph` documentation (type `?graph.data.frame` and scroll down). I plot a relationship between individual actors and use `advice` column as an indicator of the strength of the relationship. For some wild reason, i would like to scale the values of the quality of the advice by the average of the age of the recipient and provider of the advice.

I am able to do the scaling before I create the graph data frame(i have my edges and nodes as two separate data.tables so all i would have to do is bunch of joining + some sorcery as my real case is a bit more complicated than the example below), but I am curious how to do it after the igraph data frame is created.

```
actors <- data.frame(name=c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David",
                            "Esmeralda"),
                     age=c(48,33,45,34,21),
                     gender=c("F","M","F","M","F"))
relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David",
                               "David", "Esmeralda"),
                        to=c("Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Alice"),
                        same.dept=c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),
                        friendship=c(4,5,5,2,1,1), advice=c(4,5,5,4,2,3))


# create graph data frame
# note that i treat the network as undirected here
g <- graph.data.frame(relations, directed=FALSE, vertices=actors)
print(g, e=TRUE, v=TRUE)

# plot a graph of the network
plot(g,
     edge.label = edge_attr(g, 'advice'),
     vertex.label = paste0(vertex_attr(g, 'name'),
                           '\nage = ',
                            vertex_attr(g, 'age')))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "scale"?   If you have an edge weight and the corresponding node weights,  what function of them would you compute?

Comment: I want to divide the two

Comment: In this case it will be something like `advice/(mean(age_of_node_1, age_of_node_2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to what you are trying to compute is the `ends` function which gives the two ends of an edge.

```
E(g)$ScaledAdvice = 0
for(e in E(g)) {
    E(g)$ScaledAdvice[e] =  E(g)$advice[e] / mean(V(g)[ends(g, e)]$age)
}
```

Comment: I did not know about this function. This is good, thank you very much